# put text 20px below body element

Tags: html, css

When i add some text in the `body` of my `HTML` page, the text appears right on top. What i want to do is to make the text appear `20px` below from the page. How can i do this?

I tried adding padding but it gives a padding to all four sides. My code is as follows:

```
..
<body >
Hello World
</body >
...
```

In the above example the text `Hello World` appears right on top. Instead i want it to appear some `20px` below the page.

Can someone please help me out here.

Comment: add this css `body {padding-top: 20px;}`

Comment: Add what you tried so we can point out the problem.

Comment: And have you tried reading the CSS reference?

Comment: You can always declare separately `padding-top: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
padding-left: 20px;`. Here all you have to do is `padding-top:20px`

Comment: You can read this quick guide on margins, padding and the box model http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/beginner/margins/

Answer (score 2):

You cannot really style that text directly because there is no Tag or anything around it.

But couldnt you just do this?

```
body {
padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Here is some more information about padding:

[CSS-Padding Reference from Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding)

Comment: Please refrain from referencing W3Schools. Find out more here: http://www.w3fools.com/ . Although that page is okay, it's not a best practice.

Comment: While I personally think W3Schools gives enough information to get a begginer atleast "familiar" with certain attributes. I changed the link to a Document out of the Mozilla Docs.

Comment: @MathewMacLean I agree with Schneez, in fact even some experienced ones can find some quick reference of some forgotten knowledge in that site. Also you can see many technologies introduced there, knowing a name of some technology is a good start. And the last, I just feel that site is not well updated (lacks some info, reference, ...) ***but*** I don't think that site is inaccurate, it just lacks some reference (not sufficient enough) so it's not really something we have to boycott like what w3fools.com suggests.